# Is this normal for partitions? Wan't to dual-boot Windows

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, partitioning

So I recently wiped my computer, which had Xubuntu and Windows 10 dual-booted. My goal is to dual boot Windows again, but I want to make sure nothing goes wrong. I am wondering if this is normal and I won't run into any problems installing Windows.

First thing is I cannot get 'gparted' to run, I've tried reinstalling to no avail. Regardless, let me get to my question.

The output of 'sudo fdisk -l' is what is concerning me.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2e924dd6

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 608555007 608552960 290.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       608557054 625141759  16584706   7.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       608557056 625141759  16584704   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

is it normal to have a partition on /dev/sda5? Am I able to remove the partition on /sda5 without running into any issues?

Sorry if this is a dumb question just a little bit concerned about how to proceed.

Comment: Yes, the /dev/sda5 is normal.  With drives that are formatted as DOS, there is a limitation of 4 Primary partitions, so all Logical partitions will have to start with sda5 and so on.  You could remove it it, but it might cause an issue with your system as it is the swap partition that is used when your RAM gets full and needs to swap data out so you don't lose anything.

Comment: /dev/sda5 says it's formatted as swap. Swap is essentially where your system puts files when it neds to clear up space in the ram. It is recommended, but not required, to have some swap available for the system. You should be fine removing it, although you may want to add more elsewhere. Read more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: Thank you! I also got gparted to work again. I needed to reinstall 'libgtkmm' for some reason, must have had a botched installation. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.